# To Load Data into GridView pages taking some time to Display

Tags: vb.net, gridview, datatable, dataset

From the below code `// Doing some operations` is taking for some seconds maybe around 30 to 40 seconds while page loading. Then I am Calling `Method()`. When I Click page Index 4(Page number 4 in GridView), For showing page number 4 also its taking same time(30 to 40 seconds). But I need it really quick. How should I change my code? Code in VB.NET

```
Protected Sub Page_Load1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    // Doing some operations
    Method()
End Sub

Protected Sub GridView1_PageIndexChanging(sender As Object, e As GridViewPageEventArgs) Handles GridView1.PageIndexChanging
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
    GridView1.DataBind()
End Sub

Private Sub Method()
    Dim sqlConnect As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(Connection String)
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim ds As DataSet
    Dim sqlString = "SELECT * FROM Table"
    Dim Command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sqlString, sqlConnect)
    adapter.SelectCommand = Command
    adapter.Fill(ds)
    GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
    GridView1.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Comment: You indent code by 4 spaces. You can also select all the code and use the `{}` button to do it in one go (I believe Ctrl+K is a shortcut for it).

Comment: Google "wpf paginating a gridview" to get ahead.  And look how they present the results of a query with fifty thousand matches.

Comment: Do you need to select everything from the table?  How many records and columns are you returning?

Comment: @Jason Bayldon Around 80k rows and 10 columns